# How can I count the number of columns in a file?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to code a program that allows me to count the number of columns in a file (in the example below `datos.txt`). However, gfortran tells me there is an error:

> "Expected variable in read statement".

How can I solve this? In the example, I used 100 as the maximum number of columns possible. The real value is 5.

What I have tried is this:

```
program contarcolumnas

implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
implicit integer*8 (i-n)

open (50, file="datos.txt")

m=1

dimension matrizfichero(1,100)

do i=1,1
   read(50,*)(matrizfichero(i,j),j=1,m)
   if (iostat /= 0) then
      m=m+1
   else
      print*,m
   end if
end do

close(50)

end program contarcolumnas
```

Comment: Why should `iostat` have any value?  There's nothing here defining it?

Comment: That's not the only compiler error you get, is it ?  The first error is the occurrence of the `dimension` statement in a place where it shouldn't be.  Fortran is quite particular about the ordering of statements in source code.  Fix that and see what happens.

Comment: If the data is a .csv file, then usually reading it to a string first can allow one to go from there to finding the commas that separate the values... So you read(50,*) for every line or row, and then a read for each value or column.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022062) answer your question?